# Can I still add changes to CSS after precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Once I've done `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

It seems that it created something like `application-e24jrjf834jg93bwuk13uy5gfd1y24f.css`
Then when I access to the page, that is called from my app.

In development mode, I could add changes to just to css file and it applied.
In production mode, can I still add little changes to css?
If possible, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` to `true` in your **production.rb** file then all you need to do is restart your server. Otherwise just delete the precompiled assets by running `bundle exec rake assets:clean` and precompile assets again `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`.

Comment: Thanks! For my situation, it takes to finish precompile over 10 minutes. Is it supposed to be normal??

Comment: Which rails version are you using? It seems to have issues with uglifier version that was being used as the default assets compressor before rails 3.1. You can use the uglifier 1.0.2 or later version.

Comment: It should not take that much of time anyway. Are you using bootstrap? if yes, which version. Can you please provide your server details and gems(with version) those add assets to your app. Or may be you could add a different question on stack overflow. People usually don't reply the questions in comments. :)

Comment: Okay I will make another question with more details. Hold on please